# Getting the amount of memory used, both objectively and as a % of available

Tags: php, unix

I would like to get the % of memory used by a program I am trying to run. It'll only be run on a Unix-based environment.

As far as I can tell, this should be `real_usage()` or `memory_get_usage()` in PHP, but I am unaware which is what I am supposed to use - there's little documentation and some documentation says that this is not possible.

I want to disallow a certain condition from executing once 75% of the available memory is used, or 125MB - whichever is first. How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP script you can add the follow check to see if the process is about 125MB:

```
 if( round(memory_get_usage(true)/1048576) < 125) {
     //do your stuff here....
  }
```

This will only inform you on the memory used by the current PHP script.

For entire system memory and percentage in Linux, have php open the local file `/proc/meminfo`.  It continually updates itself and the first 2 lines of the file have the current memory max and usage.  You can use that to calculate the percentage for the whole system.

You can use good-old `file()` to read `/proc/meminfo` into an array, then parse the integers from the first 2 array members.

Good Luck!

Comment: Would using free -m also work?

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/01/11/free-memory-on-linux-free-m-vs-proc-meminfo

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Yes, but you'd have to run `exec()` to run the local command.  I'm religiously against using php's `exec` function unless no other options exist, you can google around to see the dangers you have cautious about using `exec`

Comment: Do I need any specific path settings for /proc/meminfo? I tried using exec("free -m"); and got SWAP 0 0 0. That's obviously not correct. I've also tried to read /proc/meminfo and I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Can you log onto the machine and run: `cat /proc/meminfo`? Are you on a shared host or do you have a dedicate machine/image?  Are you on a linux, BSD, or other type of unix  based system?  If you're developing on a Mac for instance, you won't have a /proc directory, but it will exist on the linux server you push it to.

Comment: I believe the machine is dedicated CentOS - it's a staging server through my new job. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Ah, cat /proc/meminfo worked from the root directory.

Comment: It seems like it would simply by an array of values I would need to parse. Hrm. I'm wondering why it wasn't print_r ing when I opened it. I'll see what else I can do.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Change it to `<?php $freemem = file("/proc/meminfo"); print_r($freemem); ?> `

Comment: @AndrewAlexander yes, the full path from root is needed :)

Comment: Hrm, one additional problem - it has this information as a string - would the most efficient way of getting the integer just be to trim off all non-number values?

Comment: Got this too, just used preg_replace.